# Django: All objects AND all M2M related fields in one query

Tags: django, m2m, django-select-related

Let's say I have these:

```
class Publication(models.Model):        
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through='Authorship')

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=64)
```

How can I get ALL the publications AND their author(s) in one query. I want to list each publication and its authors on a page.
But I don't want to hit the authors table for every publication.

The only way I know to do it is with `select_related` in the view and `authorship_set.all()` on the template. But that's one query for every publication. I could easily do it with raw sql, but that's yucky.

*BTW, I'm using the through model because I have to keep some extra data in there, like `author_display_order`.

EDIT:

Turns out `authorship_set` was doing all the querying.

When I run it this way from console only one query gets fired:

```
pubs = Publication.objects.all().prefetch_related('author')
for p in pubs:
    print p.title
    for a in p.author.all():
        print a.last_name
```

Comment: Have you tried `prefetch_related`?

Comment: I have, but `authorship_set.all()` still hits the db.

Comment: That seems strange... you'll need to post your code if you'd like more helpful suggestions. You can always read the Publication and Author models in two queries and combine them manually..

Comment: I think I have it. `authorship_set.all()` is the wrong way. Using `author.all()` seems to do right. I'll edit the question to reflect my findings.